# php.ini 'date.timezone' doesn't have any effect

Tags: php, datetime, time, timezone

In my **php.ini** I've set:

```
date.timezone = "Etc/UTC"
```

And the server's time is UTC+0 too, but when I try this script to get the timezone:

```
<?php print(date_default_timezone_get()); ?>
```

it returns

> Europe/Berlin

which is `UTC+2` and not `UTC+0` and I don't see how it gets there.

Just to clearify:

- I have saved the the correct file at the correct path and restarted my server
- I do not want to modify my scripts, because I already used `date()` way to often
- I want the time to be `UTC+0` for PHP just by changing the configuration
- I want it to be `UTC+0` at all times, ignoring Summer-/Wintertime

Comment: print(date_default_timezone_get()) check this before your operation

Comment: Summer/wintertime?

Comment: Europe/Berlin is not UTC

Comment: that means you have set date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin'); somewhere in script ??

Comment: @MineshPatel I know, but I want it to be UTC

Comment: use DateTime class

Comment: @MineshPatel I want to keep my date() functions, because I used them like way to often.

Comment: there is only 2 way. find from where it override timezone or change your code

Comment: $date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); 
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));    
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s a'); this will gives you date time in UTC

Comment: print phpinfo() and check value of Default timezone and date.timezone they set to UTC or Europe/Berlin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, [Minesh Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5336832/minesh-patel) told me to check if there is something overwriting my option, so I searched through my **php.ini** for `Europe/Berlin` and it turns out there was another `date.timezone`-entry that overwrote it.

Answer (score 4):

That line is certainly the correct place to change the **default** timezone.

1. Are you actually changing the right php.ini? Some setups can have multiple .ini files. Run `phpinfo();` and check *Loaded Configuration File* to see if it's that file.
2. Check if there are no other definitions of that parameter in the file. It might override what you've set if you just copy-pasted it in wherever.
3. Check if the code does not override what you have set in the .ini file. [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) sets it (and overrides) in PHP.
4. Check `phpinfo()` for more info on what the current timezone is.

Comment: The timezone is UTC+2 (Europe/Berlin) for some reason and I don't know what is overriding it. Also the config is correct.

Comment: @timmyRS what was the issue ?

Comment: @MineshPatel wrote it in my question. there really was something in the config overriding it...

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the "TZ" environment variable for your web server user? If it is set, the date.timezone php.init setting would not work as expected, like stated in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone):

> date.timezone string
>   The default timezone used by all date/time functions. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this would only work if the TZ environment variable was not set. The precedence order for which timezone is used if none is explicitly mentioned is described in the date_default_timezone_get() page.

Comment: I really don't have an idea about what an "TZ" variable is and where to find it ._.

Comment: If you are on Linux, just type `echo $TZ` to see the current setting or `export TZ=UTC` to set it. But you must do it as the web server user before starting the server. This is normally done in a init script at boot time. Try `redhat-config-date` or `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` to configure it (depending on the Linux distribution you use)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to refer this list in order to choose your timezone:

[PHP timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

**Warning:** Do not use any of the timezones listed in the following link, they only exist for backward compatible reasons, **besides UTC**:

[PHP timezones only for backward compatible reasons](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php)

It is strongly recommended that you use the correct time zone for your location, such as *Europe/Berlin*:

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin"
```

Comment: My problem is that the timezone already IS Europe/Berlin, but SHOULD be UTC+0

Answer (score 0):

Find "Europe/Berlin" in your php.ini file (get correct path to file with phpinfo();)

In some cases "date.timezone" parameters appears twice in file.

Be sure tu put correct timezones, from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.php) (php timezones)