# Have Set date.timezone, Why PHP still Showing UTC Times?

Tags: php, timezone

I've set date.timezone=Australia/Melbourne in my php.ini file. However, I am getting back UTC times. Details as follows.

As per phpinfo, I edited Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php.ini

I've set:

```
date.timezone = Australia/Melbourne
```

Also tried "Australia/Melbourne"

date.timezone isn't in any of the files in this directory:

/etc/php-7.3.d

I'm running NGINX and php-fpm I've tried restarting multiple times.

service php-fpm restart

Here is some simple test code:

```
echo date_default_timezone_get() . "<br/>";
echo ini_get('date.timezone') . "<br/>";
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
echo $date;
```

On another machine with similar setup I get the LOCAL time:

```
Australia/Melbourne
Australia/Melbourne
05/02/2019 07:05:05 pm
```

Whereas, on the problem server I get UTC time:

```
Australia/Melbourne
Australia/Melbourne
05/02/2019 09:05:05 am
```

Linux says the date time on the problem instance is:

```
Thu May  2 19:05:00 AEST 2019
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks brettsh

Comment: Did you make sure that the INI file you edited is also the INI file that is used by PHP? Look for "Loaded Configuration File" in `phpinfo()` and compare the path of the file you edited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php.ini 'date.timezone' doesn't have any effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977076/php-ini-date-timezone-doesnt-have-any-effect)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the file I edited (/etc/php.ini) was determined by "Loaded Configuration File" value in phpinfo.php. That's actually a softlink to /etc/php-7.3.ini however, I am editing the correct file.

I'm certain "Australia/Melbourne" is a valid timezone.

I've since tried:

```
export TZ='Australia/Melbourne'
```

adding the following to www.conf

```
php_admin_value[date.timezone] = Australia/Melbourne
```

Searched to see if date.timezone set differently elsewhere:

```
grep -rn "date.timezone" /etc/
```

Searched for UTC:

```
grep -rn "UTC" /etc/
```

Even tried this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
```

Maybe this is my problem:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77582

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it *was* an issue with that version of PHP.

All I needed to do was upgrade from PHP 7.3.2 to 7.3.4.

I'm running AWS Linux so, I just ran this:

```
yum update
```